# How to disable the Wi-Fi button on a laptop keyboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard

How do I disable the Wi-Fi button on my laptop's keyboard?
I think it can be done by changes in the regisrty or .inf files, because the HP's HotKey utility doesn't have this option.

Laptop model: HP Probook 4320s
OS : Windows 7

I'd prefer not to install 3rd party software, but if there is no other way, this is an acceptable option.

Comment: Could the option be in the BIOS?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masking_tape).
[image]